# Cannot access google through proxy (tried Squid and tinyproxy)

Tags: proxy, squid, tinyproxy

I am using a ec2 instance in AWS as a proxy server, proxy software was installed on the server (I tried squid and tinyproxt, most sites can be accessed through proxy, but google cannot.
In tiny proxy log, I got something like this:

Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Connect (file descriptor 3): ---------------(masked)
Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Request (file descriptor 3): GET http://www.bing.com/ HTTP/1.1
Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: No upstream proxy for [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com)
Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: opensock: opening connection to [www.bing.com:80](http://www.bing.com:80)
Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: opensock: getaddrinfo returned for [www.bing.com:80](http://www.bing.com:80)
Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Established connection to host "www.bing.com" using file descriptor 4.
Nov 10 03:54:27 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Closed connection between local client (fd:3) and remote client (fd:4)

Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Connect (file descriptor 3): ---------------(masked)
Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Request (file descriptor 3): GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: No upstream proxy for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: opensock: opening connection to [www.google.com:80](http://www.google.com:80)
Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: opensock: getaddrinfo returned for [www.google.com:80](http://www.google.com:80)
Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: Established connection to host "www.google.com" using file descriptor 4.
Nov 10 03:54:37 ip-172-31-24-2 tinyproxy[2847]: process_server_headers failed: Connection reset by peer. host "www.google.com" using file descriptor 4.

As you can see, bing can be accessed, while google cannot

Confirmed that:

1. Google can be accessed ON the server.
2. Most of other sites can be accessed through proxy.
3. Similiar behavior for both squid and tinyproxt

Comment: How is this a programming-related question?